# moveit path planning problem

Tags: ros, moveit, path

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i planned a path and execute it using move it.The path is executed by ABB robot 2400.It is moved by using instruction group.asyncMove(). While it is executing a path can i stop the robot in the middle using instruction group.stop().I tried it but it is not working what is the problem.Is there any problem with the header file

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250590/moveit-path-planning-problem/) by [anadgopi1994](https://answers.ros.org/users/28124/anadgopi1994/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2016-12-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I do not see why this should not work from MoveIt's point of view.
The stop-request is forwarded to the FollowJointTrajectory action-server that executes the trajectory.
Whether this action server then aborts the trajectory is up to him.
I seem to recall that ros-control based systems will still try to execute the rest of the trajectory even if they are asked to abort.
So what implements your FollowJointTrajectory action server?

---

Originally posted by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) with karma: 2950 on 2016-12-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0